# How to use await in the function with MySQL.?

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I am working in `Node-js` Now I use `MySQL` for storing the data. I want to store the data user data in the database. after adding the user I want to return the `userId` as an authentication token. I use the following code

```
router.post('/signup', [
    body('username', "enter username of min 4 character").isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body('firstName', "enter firstName of min 3 character").isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body('lastName', "enter lastname of min 3 character").isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body('password', "enter password of min 4 character").isLength({ min: 4 }),
    body('city', "enter city of min 4 character").isLength({ min: 4 }),
    body('email', "entera valid email").isEmail()
], async(req, res) => {
    const error = validationResult(req);
    if (!error.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: error.array() });
    }
    else {

        var salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        console.log("salt is ",salt);
        var password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,salt);
        console.log("password is ",password);
        // if the input is valid then start to check the user
        connection.connect(function (err) {
            var query = `INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, username, email, city, password) VALUES ("${req.body.firstName}","${req.body.lastName}","${req.body.username}","${req.body.email}","${req.body.city}","${password}")`;
            console.log(query);
            connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({ error: "given email or username is already exist" });
                }
                else {
                    console.log("inserted");
                    var data = {};
                    // return res.json(res.body);
                    var query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "${req.body.email}"`;
                    console.log(query);
                    const user =  connection.query(query, (err, result) => {
                        data = result;
                    });
                    console.log("data is ",data);
         
                    // data = {
                    //     user:{
                    //         id:"123"
                    //     }
                    // };
                    const authToken = jwt.sign(data,JWT_SECRATE);
                    return res.status(200).json({ authToken });
                }
            });
        });


    }
});
```

After storing the user in the database. I return a user-auth by their ID. I use the query to check the ID. but I cannot use await in this statement. Now What I do to do this task.

Comment: It seems, you don't have to use await, as you're using the callback approach. This code should be working without await, I think you don't need await, can you please let us know where exactly in code you still have issue?

Comment: mysql package doesn't supoprt promises, you have to use mysql2 for that

Answer (score 0):

Better start using ORM ex. https://openbase.com/js/prisma

The way you wrote is old way.

Or use this library mysql2/promise. You can get rid of writing call back hell hierarchy and the promise wrapper around teh SQL queries.

Ref : https://knowledgeacademy.io/node-js-mysql-transaction/